# How do I upgrade the default torrent client (Transmission) in 16.04?

Tags: updates, 16.04, transmission, torrent-client

I have read [the Changelog](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/Changes) and I am very keen to upgrade Xenial's default torrent client Transmission. There have been *many* improvements and bug fixes since Transmission version 2.84 which comes with Xenial, a version released in 2014!

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default Xenial Xerus 16.04 LTS carries quite an *aged* version of `Transmission`. There is an outside chance that a newer version *may* come through Ubuntu Backports but for the moment there is a very solid and stable PPA that carries the most recent version.

To add this PPA and then install the very latest version (2.9.2) run the following commands in a Terminal window:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:transmissionbt/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install transmission
```

And this is enough to get you the very latest `Transmission` complete with all of the recent security updates and improvements. A screenshot from my own Xenial system:

[image]

There have been several releases in 2016 (2.90 and 2.92), with the promise of more to come, so having the PPA added to your system ensures that you will stay up to date when future releases of `Transmission` are rolled out.

**References:**

- [Transmission Changelogs](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/Changes)
- [PPA: “transmissionbt” team](https://launchpad.net/~transmissionbt/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)